Two different meta descriptions are showing for single post. NEED HELP
So my website has a blog post https://example.com/keyword-keyword2-keyword3/ which is indexed on google. But when I check site:https://example.com/keyword-keyword2-keyword3/. The meta description which i put on Yoast shows. And then I again check site:https://example.com, some different meta description shows.
Can you please explain what's going on, or how to resolve it?
These are two screenshot attached below



The most common reason that Google shows a different meta description than the one you provided, is that they think that their snippet is better (for that search, for that user). Google's aim is to help users to get the right content to answer their questions and to solve their problems.
